# undefined in php script

Tags: php, javascript, lightbox

Why am I getting an undefined under the large photo when I click on a thumbnail here and how do I fix this?  I have tried commenting out everything here to no effect?  Here is the code and a URL for review:

http://tinyurl.com/6pbkhg7

```
<td><div id="loadarea" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
<img width="400" height="300" src="http://www.mydomain.com/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/<?php echo(rawurlencode($row['ListingRid'])); ?>_1.jpg" alt="<?php echo(rawurlencode($row['MLNumber'])); ?>" align="left"  border="0">
</div>

<?
$image = "<br>";
$ListingRid = $row['ListingRid'];
$img_cnt = 1;
//$image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_1.jpg rel=\"enlargeimage\" rev=\"targetdiv:loadarea,trigger:click\"><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_1.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
for ($c=1;$c<10;$c++) {
    if ($c<10)
        $c_ext = $c;
    else
        $c_ext = $c;

    if (file_get_contents("http://www.mydomain.com/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg"))
        $image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg rel=\"enlargeimage\" rev=\"targetdiv:loadarea,trigger:click\"><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
    else
        $c=12;
    $img_cnt++;
    if ($img_cnt == 5) {
        $image .= "<br>";
        $img_cnt = 0;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are missing the title tag

try this with title:

```
$image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg rel=\"enlargeimage\" rev=\"targetdiv:loadarea,trigger:click\" title=\"THIS IS TITLE\"><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
```

or this without title:

```
$image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg rel=\"enlargeimage\" rev=\"targetdiv:loadarea,trigger:click\" title=\"\"><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
```

lightbox requires a title, you should set `title=""` if you don't want anything there.